# Games slowing down with Xbox Wireless controller on PC

Tags: pc, controllers

I have recently noticed that my games are very slow while using the Xbox Wireless controller with my computer. I originally thought my computer had slowed down but I also tried configuring my PS3 controller over Bluetooth and I noticed that the slowness is completely gone.

I tried both controllers on Borderlands 2 and Tomb Raider. In both games, even if I reduce the graphics to minimum 800x600 resolution and put all settings to lowest, there are still lags in the game time to time.

Note that this is not lag with the controller commands. The buttons I press respond just fine, but the game itself freezes or framerate drops while I'm using the Xbox wireless controller. But when I use the PS3 controller, I can run both games at 1200x800 resolution and some graphics settings at medium.

It happens with both my Mac and my PC.

What could be the cause of this slowdown and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a post on [Xbox Support forums](http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_360_support/f/7/p/1586275/4113115.aspx) many users face this issue on Windows 8, but not 7.

If you are using Windows 8 you'll have to hope and wait for a driver update then it seems.

Comment: Hey there. Welcome to Arqade, and thanks for getting involved and posting an answer. This site doesn't really function like a forum though, and you really shouldn't post speculative answers if possible. Because you're unsure, your answer may attract a few downvotes, but don't be too disheartened by that.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the welcome. Since he didn't specify whether he's using Windows 8 I cannot be sure that's his problem. If it is, it is official though: http://forums.xbox.com/xbox_forums/xbox_support/xbox_360_support/f/7/p/1586275/4113115.aspx
As I lack the reputation to make a comment I could only answer, risking that it's not an answer if he's not using Windows 8.

Comment: Ok - I'd definitely suggest editing your answer to include that link :) so people know it's not just speculation that it's a known issue.

Comment: @shanodin SE questions are resources for everybody who is facing a given problem, even if an answer does not help the OP it might help others.

Comment: Thanks Robotnik. I am using Windows 8 but it's also the same on my Mac (OS Mavericks). I had a feeling it was driver issues anyway but I couldn't find the Xbox forum with this question, so I asked one here. Thank you.

Comment: @kotekzot I'm not seeing your point...

Answer (score 0):

You should check for a process called Xboxstat.exe. If you find it in Task Manager, end the process and disable up in Startup.

Answer (score -1):

this method worked well in my case where my game lagged when using controller but was smooth with keyboard

Comment: It's best to summarize the main points of a video in case the link or video ever goes down.